# PowerShell script to set ACLs on a folder only works on some computers

Tags: powershell

Could someone tell my why this PowerShell code works on some machines but not others?  I'm trying to add the local NT Authority\Authenticated Users to a folder.  On a majority of computers it works fine, but on others I get the error "Exception calling "SetAccessRule" with "1" argument(s): "Some or all identity references could not be translated."
I've tried this both running under SYSTEM and as an administrator.

```
$AuthenticatedUsersSID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier 'S-1-5-11'
$ACL = Get-Acl -Path "$($env:ProgramData)\MTSLogs" | select -ExpandProperty Access | where IdentityReference -eq "NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if (!(($ACL.FileSystemRights -eq "Modify, Synchronize") -and($ACL.AccessControlType -eq "Allow") -and ($ACL.InheritanceFlags -eq "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit"))) {
    Write-Output "ACL is incorrect.  Remediating..."
    $NewACL = Get-Acl -Path "$($env:ProgramData)\MTSLogs"
    $AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($AuthenticatedUsersSID,"Modify","3","0","Allow")
    $NewACL.SetAccessRule($AccessRule)
    $NewACL | Set-Acl -Path "$($env:ProgramData)\MTSLogs"
}
```

Comment: Which version of PowerShell is being used on working and non-working systems? `$PSVersionTable`

Comment: Do you get the same error is you use this command instead? : $AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("Authenticated Users","Modify","3","0","Allow")

Comment: lit: It's running with PowerShell 5.1 on all machines.
Zivkok: Yes, I originally tried both "NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users" and "Authenticated Users".  Same issue.